# How to get length of audio file (MP3, MP4, WAV, etc.) in Rust?

Tags: audio, rust, metadata

I am trying to get the length of an audio file and am not sure how. Do I need codecs or can this be derived from metadata? if codecs, are there any recommendations out there?

I have tried using file::metadata and read different crates such as rodio, but haven't found a way to determine file length.

Comment: https://docs.rs/metadata/latest/metadata/media_file/struct.MediaFileMetadata.html#method.new

Comment: metadata::media_file::MediaFileMetadata::new(&std::path::Path::new("/mnt/file1.mp3")).unwrap()._duration